# glColor4f() - effect of alpha value

Tags: c, opengl, opengl-es

I am using glColor4f(). Surprisingly, changing the alpha, i.e., the fourth argument doesn't cause any change in transparency. The code segment is:

```
const GLfloat squareVertices[] = { 
0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 
-0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 
0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
-0.5, -0.5, 0.0}; 

glEnableClientState (GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glColor4f (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5);
glLoadIdentity ();       
glTranslatef(0, 0, -5);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, squareVertices);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

Any pointers to where I could be going wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to enable blending if you want to use transparency:

`glEnable(GL_BLEND)`;

See also [glBlendFunc](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glBlendFunc) to setup the blending function.

Comment: Nice answer, @Tim. It's usage is pretty well documented on the OpenGL wiki, but here goes a sample blend function, just in case: `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`

Answer (score 3):

Both existing answers and the comments below them are very helpful! The only thing that you should know is that **the order matters**.

First, specify the blend function, then enable the feature.

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_BLEND)
```